# android ListLayout mix type rows

Tags: android, listview

Hello I am new in Android, I am looking for create menu.

I am using this one popular menu guide.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Menu Aim : 
At top Userinformation incase already logged in or Login/Register button if not login at bottom I use ListView. Is there anyway I can put first row as userinformation row and rest with menu item.

Please check attach screen source.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

:)

Comment: All you need is to use Material Drawer Layout. Please have a look at this tutorial http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you don't need ListView with mixed-type rows. You can simply use header and footer view for ListView by calling `list.addHeaderView(view)` and `list.addFooterView(view)`.

The whole top panel can be your list header. Checkout this  example
[ListView Header in Android](https://stacktips.com/articles/listview-header-parallax-in-android)

Comment: Thank you so much you have save my time.

Comment: Can you help me I am looking for list with ads after 4 row.

That means row 1,2,3,4 contain regular row but row 5 contain ads image only ..

Thanks

Comment: checkout this example. https://stacktips.com/articles/listview-with-section-header-in-android